# Disabling Canvas entrance transtion

Tags: xaml, canvas, windows-8, winrt-xaml, transition

**Nevermind. The issue was that I needed to disable transitions for the contained object which happened to be a Listview. had to disable the ItemContainerTransitions collection.**

I dynamically add and remove elements from a Canvas element. When I do, the elements do that nice automatic animation which is completely unneeded for me (since I do all my own animation in this case).

I tried putting an empty TransitionCollection in the Canvas element in XAML and it does not seem to have any effect. I also tried adding an EntranceTransition with a zero offset, but that did not help either.

How do I tell Canvas not to animate my elements as they are added?

Here's what I tried:

```
    <Canvas.Transitions>
        <TransitionCollection>
            <AddDeleteThemeTransition/>
            <EntranceThemeTransition FromHorizontalOffset="0"/>
        </TransitionCollection>
    </Canvas.Transitions>
```

and

```
    <Canvas.Transitions>
        <TransitionCollection>
        </TransitionCollection>
    </Canvas.Transitions>
```

Comment: When I try your second method, it works for me as the default transition collection is overwritten. Can you confirm you are not control templating the canvas at all?

Comment: I should have done some more testing. The animation I was seeing was not actually the canvas animation. It was the content of the control I was using (which was a ListView). I thought I disabled animations for that, but apparently I used the incorrect transition collection. Thanks.